# JSX props should not use functions react/jsx-no-bind

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

i am forking a app. but in gives me this errors. instead or arrow function what should i use or should i download any dependencies?

here is the code

```
    const modalBottom = () => {
    return (
      <ConfirmAddModalBottom
        price={price}
        currencies={currencies}
        parsedAmounts={parsedAmounts}
        noLiquidity={noLiquidity}
        onAdd={onAdd}
        poolTokenPercentage={poolTokenPercentage}
      />
    )
  }
```

error: 8:  JSX props should not use functions  react/jsx-no-bind

Comment: Can you show where you're using `modalBottom`?

Comment: ` const [onPresentAddLiquidityModal] = useModal(
    <TransactionConfirmationModal
      title={noLiquidity ? t('You are creating a pool') : t('You will receive')}
      customOnDismiss={handleDismissConfirmation}
      attemptingTxn={attemptingTxn}
      hash={txHash}
      content={() => <ConfirmationModalContent topContent={modalHeader} bottomContent={modalBottom} />}
      pendingText={pendingText}
      currencyToAdd={pair?.liquidityToken} `

Answer (score 4):

I found that the problem was solved by following the eslint documentation to [this section](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md#react-hooks).

Essentially, move any of your functions into a useCallback hook and that should stop the error.

Comment: I ran this issue down too and this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this issue occurred because I was not using the arrow function. for example the **incorrect** approach is,

```
const Component = () => {
 function foo() {
  // do something
 }
 return (
   <Image onLoad={foo} />
 )
}
```

So, the **correct** approach should be:

```
const Component = () => {
 const foo = () => {
  // do something
 }
 return (
   <Image onLoad={foo} />
 )
}
```

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Updating the image tag to `<Image onLoad={() => foo} />` will also work if you want to use `function foo()`

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could try to install jsx with npm . Like this:

npm install -g jsx

If u have any question let me know. I am also forking PCS.

Comment: still the same error, do you have this same error?

Comment: I solved it days ago. Idk what exactly what I did, But I installed ESLint and it fixed it